# How to focus a field which is in a TransientModel form in Odoo?

Tags: javascript, xml, focus, odoo, odoo-10

I've just realized that `default_focus="1"` does not work for fields in Transient Model views (at least the ones opened with `target="new"`). And `autofocus="autofocus"`, which I thought it should be used only with `buttons` or  `pages`, works for those Transient Model fields, but only the first time you open the view. It is not working again unless you reload the browser.

In my case, I did a widget for a `Char` field (inside the Transient Model), and I need this field to be focused each time the pop-up is opened. As I am not able to do it by XML, I am trying to do it in JavaScript.

This is the XML template of my widget, which is inheriting from `FieldChar`:

```
<t t-name="FieldRed" t-extend="FieldChar">
    <t t-jquery="input" t-operation="attributes">
        <attribute name="id">barcode_input</attribute>
        <attribute name="class">o_form_input bg-red</attribute>
    </t>
</t>
```

Now, the JS code of my widget. I am trying to focus it in `start` method because is the first method executed after the renderisation:

```js
start: function() {
    console.log('START');
    this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    this.$el.parent().find('input').focus();
},
```

But this is not working. I've also tried with:

```js
this.setupFocus(this.$el.parent().find('input'));
```

But nothing happened. However, if I include this line, for example, the field is automatically filled in, as expected:

```js
this.$el.parent().find('input').val('START');
```

So my question is:

How can I focus the `input` field of the widget each time the form is opened?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally, I've just found a simple workaround for this. I just wait for 50 miliseconds before calling the `focus`, with `setTimeout`. I guess the focus is automatically moved by the Odoo core to somewhere when `start` is called, if I wait for the end of that action and then move the focus wherever I want, it works. Not a solution I like, though, but at the moment it's the only one I have:

```js
start: function() {
    this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    self = this;
    setTimeout(function(){
        self.$el.parent().find('input').focus();
    }, 50);
},
```

Comment: expert level, but not useful. to just make focu in odoo in case we have to do 100 things, its bad odoo framework.

Answer (score 1):

I did it using a simple jquery.

I add a class in a field and write script inside popup for view.

just like below.

> 

```
<form string="Stock Disposal">
                <sheet>
                    <script>
                        $('.my-focus-field').focus()

                    </script>

                    <div class="oe_title">
                        <h1>
                            Stock Disposal
                        </h1>
                    </div>
                    <group>
                        <field name="serial_number" class="my-focus-field"/>
                    </group>
                </sheet>
            </form>
```

Let me know if it is wrong way.

Comment: It works like a charm when I combine both answers! Put the JS script to the form and wait for 50 ms (with `setTimeout`) before focusing.

Comment: perfectly, worked